# Google adds ryanair flight to calendar without being logged in

Tags: privacy, google

- I booked a flight with ryanair in a browser, where I'm not logged in to google or using googles search engine(I'm using **duckduckgo.com**)
- I didn't use my Google email address in ryanair!

After booking the flight and sending the pdf containing the boarding passes to someone else who print them out:

> I received an email from google that my flight had been added to my
>   calendar!

I wonder now how google could possibly know that I'm flying on that day, and more: In my calendar google added **flight time/day/booking number** etc.

Is google checking attached documents when sending an email? Could google chrome on my computer spy on opera (I was logged in in chrome but not in opera [Where I perfomed the check-in])

Or is there another way that Google knows these private information?

Thanks in advance

**using ubuntu 17.10 and wasn't using gnomes *online accounts*

EDIT:

In my google calendar is source email given: So google is checking my attachments! In Germany where I live is this illegal, did I accept something that google is allowed to read my emails and attached documents?

Comment: *"Did I accept"*: Yes, you did, check the [Google privacy policy](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/#infocollect), and in particular the section about the *"Information we get from your use of our services"* and *"Information [...] we obtain about you from partners"*. Google is located in the US, so this is not illegal. To benefit from German law you should switch to a purely german company to handle your emails.

Comment: This technical part of the question is [documented behavior](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6084018?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). If this is legal or not is not a technical question and thus off-topic - try law.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try launching the browser in incognito mode, and redoing the test.

Alternatively, you could try this experiment.  Make your own official-looking "boarding pass" in an editor, save as PDF, and email that to the same friend.  Does this information show up on your calendar?

If so, make a change to your "boarding pass," save as PDF, and encrypt it using some sort of PDF tool.  Then mail it to the same friend.  Does the information show up on your calendar?

If NOT, then make a third change, save as plaintext PDF, and mail it to the same friend.  If you see this one show up on your calendar, then it's clear (at least to me) that your attachments are being scanned by Google.

(If your friend asks for your password from step 2, then you know it's the friend doing this.  If you get no response to this experiment, then (a) your "boarding pass" doesn't look legit to Google, (b) Google's not to blame, and/or (c) your friend is wise to your experiment and is standing down.)